# Matching version for android studio in old android projects

Tags: android, gradle, ide

Android projects are really dependant on gradle version. Due to it, many of them comes with a wrapper for the working version of gradle they need, `gradlew`.

Android studio is known to need a minimal gradle version to run a project. that makes many projects unusable.

This is an example: https://github.com/google/grafika

build and install on connected device just works:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/grafika
cd grafika
chmod +x gradlew
./gradlew build
./gradlew installDebug
```

But open in android studio it ask to regenerate the wrapper and then everything breaks. Even code navigation is broke due to problems to build.

Is there any list with version of Android Studio supporting needed version for a project?

In case attached gradle needed is 3.3, what would be the matching android studio to use?

Answer (score 1):

You should focus on Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version.
The list of Android studio and AGP versions compatibility is here: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility

If the gradle version is 3.3 it means that the AGP version is something 2.x. Modern versions of Android Studio don't support it, you need something really ancient.